# Incorrect results while decrypting AES-128-ECB text

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, ecb

I have a piece of `Base64` text, which I know was encrypted in `AES-128-ECB mode`, and even know the key (`YELLOW SUBMARINE`, 16 bytes). I'm using the following code to decrypt it.

`textbox1` contains cyphertext;

`textbox2` contains the key

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Byte[] CTBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(textBox1.Text);            
        Byte[] KeyBytes = new Byte[textBox2.TextLength];
        string Key = textBox2.Text;
        Aes Decryptor = Aes.Create();
        Decryptor.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        Decryptor.BlockSize = 128;
        for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < textBox2.Text.Length; iCounter++)            
            KeyBytes[iCounter] = Convert.ToByte(textBox2.Text[iCounter]);          
        Decryptor.KeySize = KeyBytes.Length * 8;
        Decryptor.Key = KeyBytes;            
        Decryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        ICryptoTransform Decr = Decryptor.CreateDecryptor();
        Byte[] plainText = null;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Decr, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(CTBytes, 0, CTBytes.Length);
            }

            plainText = ms.ToArray();
        }                        
        string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainText);
        textBox3.Text = s;
        string s1 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
        textBox2.Text = s1;
    }
```

The result, however, is incorrect (meaningless). Is there something I've missed? I can provide the cyphertext as well if that's necessary.

Update: the ciphertext

```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```

Comment: Have you tried ASCII encoding your key instead? Note that keys normally are never ever strings. If this is a tutorial, it is pretty well explaining how not to do crypto for now (ECB, no padding, strings for keys etc.). `"YELLOW SUBMARINE"` is 16 characters, not necessarily 16 bytes and C# uses 16 bit little endian encodings for characters, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please post base 64 text to check if my answer is correct... Hopefully my Mono dev. groks the source code. For that matter, please create a separate method to perform the decryption instead of putting it all in the GUI class.

Comment: Yes, it's a tutorial. I'm not sure I undersand what does 'ASCII encoding' mean. Isn't it the same thing that I do?

Comment: Also one of the tasks is to detect a string which was ECB-encrypted in a file which contains 100+ strings. I'm having trouble with that one too because simply trying to find identical substrings as advised in the taskbook doesnt really give anything good.

Comment: I mean `Byte[] KeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("YELLOW SUBMARINE");`

Comment: I used your variant and the result is just the same. Seems that the problem is somewhere else

Comment: For the other problem: look for repetitions of 16 byte blocks. Don't confuse bytes and characters! It's one of the most common mistakes here on SO with regards to crypto.

Comment: For that other thing, strings are in hex. So do I get it right that 16 bytes would be 32 hex characters? There aren't any repetitions of such blocks, biggest I managed to discover was like 5 bytes, unless search algorythm was bad.

Comment: Well, I cannot solve your problem above neither. Please double check your input and the questions.